# How to use jq to produce multiple JSON objects?

Tags: json, jq

How would one transform a `JSON` object into several derived `JSON` objects with `jq`?

Example input:

```json
[
  {
     "id": 1,
     "a": "value-in-a",
     "b": "value-in-b"
  },
  {
     "id": 2,
     "c": "value-in-c"
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```json
[
  {
     "id": "1",
     "value": "value-in-a"
  },
  {
     "id": "1",
     "value": "value-in-b"
  },
  {
     "id": "2",
     "value": "value-in-c"
  }
]
```

Here the output is an array with 3 elements. First 2 elements are transformed using the first element in the input array. Third element is produced from second element in the input array.

I assume to achieve there will need to be several steps:

a) Construct 2 objects from single JSON object input.  Aassume this can be done using variables. First assign input object into variable, then construct object with value a and then with value b.  Not sure how to make JQ return several constructed JSON objects.

b) Conditionals will need to be used to not produce an object if `a`, or `b`, or `c` is missing. This can probably be done using 'alternative' operator or `if-then-else`

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the other keys using `del` and `keys_unsorted`:

```sh
jq 'map({id, value: (del(.id) | .[keys_unsorted[]])})'
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "value-in-a"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "value-in-b"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": "value-in-c"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/FCP0tp96Fd)

Comment: Same output with one `()` omitted: `map({id, value: .[del(.id) | keys_unsorted[]]})`